# Facebook API call return empty dataset after 30 item

Tags: facebook

I want to get all results from `/search` call. But after 30 items, it returns me empty data with no explain at all:

`{'__debug__': {}, 'data': []}` (or `{'data': []}` without debug param)

It's no matter what limit I put, it create more/less pages, I can navigate between them with `next` and `prev` links but all this stop working when I trying to get 31+ item. In graph api testing tool it works as expected. I can dive as long as I want.

So my question is: how to fix that? Is this some facebook limiter? Or probably I need to publish my app first?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook gives some basic info, if you want more info you have to create your api in the fb developer app(https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps%2F).

In this they will ask you about your site info and why you need those information. if they are satisfied they will provide all the info you need.